# PHP Error, what did i do wrong?

Tags: php

Bent u **geinspireerd** door deze vragen?  *Ja / Nee*  
            
            " />
            " />
            " />
            " />
            " />
            " />
            " />
            " />
            " />
            
            
            
        Op welk levensgebied zou u het liefst **vooruitgang**  willen zien? 
        
          
          
         
         
        " />
        " />
        " />
        " />
        " />
        " />
        " />
        " />
        
        
        
    
    Kunt u nu een cijfer geven  **per levensgebied**  ? 
      
     
      
     
     
     
     
     
    " />
    " />
    " />
    " />
    
    
    
    Welke  **4**  levensgebieden vindt u belangrijk? 
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    ?>

What is wrong? I get this error: 
 syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBSITES\index.php on line 20

Don't know, could you help?

Comment: Ohh i found the problem!

Comment: Within two minutes of posting the question? Don't you think that posting it at all was a little premature then?!

Comment: stap4 is false, it must be $stap4...

Comment: and next time - please highlight your code correctly

Comment: Simple, just take out the PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM and you'll be all set.

Comment: Is that 2 dots or four dots or two dots dotted twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elseif(isset(stap4)){`

Missing `$` before  `stap4`?